# Как подгружать информацию при открытии блока?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, css

Доброго времени суток.

ПРЕДЫСТОРИЯ: Наткнулся на сайте last.fm на одну фишку. У них на сайте можно выбрать любого автора и прослушать любой трек через YouTube.

Как это работает. зайдем к примеру на страницу [Dave Gahan](https://www.last.fm/music/Dave+Gahan), выберем любой трек и нажмем проиграть (треугольник). После чего, справа снизу откроется ролик ютюба. Мы можем его закрыть и открыть следующий, и так с каждым.

Теперь о проблеме с которой я столкнулся:

Когда я пытаюсь реализовать нечто похожее на своем сайте, я стыкаюсь с проблемой, что ролик начинает подгружатся еще до того, как я нажму кнопку. Т.е. при открытии сайта (а у меня на странице 5 роликов скрытых изначально) секунд 5-7 на фоне подгружаются ролики с `display:none;`, сами ролики не видны пока я нажму на кнопку.

Теперь вопрос, как можно реализовать так, что бы ролики подгружались лишь после того как я нажму на воспроизведение а не во время загрузки страницы?

Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Пожалуйста, редактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него свой код, чтобы пользователи смогли дать лаконичный ответ. В противном случае, вопрос может быть закрыт проверяющими. Чтобы редактировать вопрос, нажмите на кнопку [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как задать хороший вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/150150)

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько путей решения:

1. Быстрый костыль - это при клике по плей в div вставлять iframe с роликом.
2. Это API Youtube https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=ru

Answer (score 0):

Если на скорую руку:

```js
var video_player = function(config) { 
 this.play_button = document.querySelectorAll('.playlist-item');
 var wrapper = document.getElementById('Wrapper');
 
 this.add = function(){
  var video_link = this.getAttribute('data-link');
  var el = document.getElementById('Iframe_window')
  if(!el) {
   var iframe_creat = document.createElement("IFRAME");
   wrapper.appendChild(iframe_creat);
   iframe_creat.setAttribute("src", video_link);
   iframe_creat.id = 'Iframe_window';
  } else {
   el.setAttribute("src", video_link);
  }
  
 }
 for (var i=0; i < this.play_button.length; i++) {
  this.play_button[i].addEventListener('click', this.add); 
 } 
}

      
var play_it = new video_player();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gidugu");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  font-family: 'Gidugu', sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 10px 10px 30px 10px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 60px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.wrapper .playlist-item {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  margin: 2px 0;
  font-size: 26px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 300ms;
  transition: 300ms;
}
.wrapper .playlist-item:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrapper" class="wrapper">
 <div class="playlist">
  <div class="playlist-item" data-link='https://www.youtube.com/embed/6GhPgnpl5Vs'>Video #1</div>
  <div class="playlist-item" data-link='https://www.youtube.com/embed/yl1PS0F7tVk'>Video #3</div>
  <div class="playlist-item" data-link='https://www.youtube.com/embed/Q1E8gruS5e4'>Video #3</div>
  
 </div>
</div>
```